# R plotting : row names as labels

Tags: r, plot

I have a single variable that I want to plot, lets say the temperature in a place. Instead of the 'index =1,2,3.." in the horizontal axis, I want the name of place that I have in another column (corresponding to temperature at that place) instead of the 1,2,3. Is there a way to do this ?

something like this :

```
place1 32

place2 33

place3 43

place4 37
```

Basically I want to be able to use a column as labels for a plot.

Comment: consider a bar plot: `barplot(df$temperature, names.arg = df$place)`.

Comment: Note that your title is conflicting with your text... are the "place<n>" strings in a separate variable or are they the row labels?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is:

```
temp <- data.frame(temperature = c(32,33,43,37), 
                   place = paste("Place", 1:4))
```

That is:

```
  temperature   place
1          32 Place 1
2          33 Place 2
3          43 Place 3
4          37 Place 4
```

You can use:

```
# Create a scatterplot, with an hidden x axis
plot(temp$temperature, pch=20, ylim=c(0, 50), 
     xaxt="n", xlab="Place", ylab="Temperature")
# Plot the axis separately
axis(1, at=1:4, labels=temp$place)
```

Or, if you want a barplot

```
barplot(temp$temperature, names.arg=rownames(temp$place))
```